# CSS - Is it possible for html in an include to ignore styles from a file referenced in the main page?

Tags: css

I've developed a dynamic ad banner that consits of html and styles loaded into the host site via javascript. On one particular site, certain styles in the stylesheet for the main page are affecting the html that I'm dynamically loading.

Is there a technique for having the dynamically loaded html only render styles from the css I have loaded along with the html, and ignoring any styles in the host page?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: How are you including the HTML? If you put it in an iframe the CSS of the containing page has no influence on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your banner into an iframe.

Comment: Most commercial ad-campaign place holders utilise iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Add !important to your CSS like

p { color: #ff0000 !important; }

Comment: That wouldn't remove the other CSS being applied from the main page. Only the common rules would be overridden.

Comment: Yes thats a problem.
We can mention the styles defined in main page in our new CSS with !important. Then may be the problem will be solved.

Comment: ...only if they're not !important in the main CSS.  If they are, then it's a question of specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is a real easy way. Why dont you have your classes separated form the main page HTML. Give them a unique identification if you want there to be no conflict.

Example

Your main page has a css class `.input`
Give your dynamically loading page as `.Dybamically_input` this will server something as a namespace.Also you can use `!important` to the properties which you definitely want to added.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that if the host page has style normal HTML elements in some way.  It's too much work.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski but it does solve the problem and some amount of name spacing is always helpful right? :)

Comment: Only if there's a collision in properties, often there is not.  You want it blue and the containing page has it bold, or underlined, or a massive line-height.  Are you going to redefine every property conceivable? Good luck.

Comment: The issues are caused more by styles in the host page that reference standard elements rather than classes - input for example. That means I get the class styling in my style sheet, plus the tag level styling

Answer (score 0):

There is an evolving standard to introduce scope blocks to CSS but that isn't yet supported enough to be of any use.  You can use the !important directive, but that is likely also to affect the underlying document if you don't apply it carefully.

The best solution is to create a scope by including all the the HTML in your add banner inside a div with a uniquely named class (and use your own namespace eg. 'cog_myAd' to try to guarantee uniqueness.  Then apply styles just to that class, using !important where you might need to override styles that could be changed lower down the cascade of styles.

Comment: Scoping style doesn't work the opposite way where you're trying to prevent global styles from affecting a specific portion of the page.

Comment: No, but you could override style for all elements within your block. This is also true for wrapping your section within a class.

Comment: Sigh, but the point is you don't know what styles to override, because the host page is not under your control...  Specifying every style conceivable would be an enormous task, even then, you may not have the specificity to trump every style in every host page.  Class based specificity is quite weak (only overrides element selectors).

Comment: But the part that is under your control is the banner, so you only need to override styles for elements appearing within the banner surely?

Comment: OK, you have an input in the banner, you want a blue background or something, nothing else, the host page wants all inputs to be hidden until a certain criteria is met, or it wants them to have rounded edges, or it wants them to be right-to-left, or rotated 45 degrees, or... anything you haven't thought of, not even CSS, the JavaScript might replace all your input field's labels and put their contents into the field values, anything that could mess up what you did in your banner, an iframe is the simplest measure, anything else will waste your time and bandwidth and therefore cost you money.

Answer (score 0):

If you have attached your CSS file to the HTML page then the only solution to it would be using `!important` for all conflicting CSS properties -

```
.className{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: This would be too much analysis for a widget that could potentially appear anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Use inline styles (the style attribute on all your banner elements you want to style) instead of external css file - this way you will never have a conflict.

The other option as others suggested is to use IFrame.

Comment: -1 That wouldn't help in this case. And using inline styles makes the content a lot harder to read.

Comment: Why that would not help? And I thought that viewing banner sources are not so popular these days :)

Comment: OP is facing issues with the stylesheet for the main page, conflicting with banner styles. Are you suggesting he remove the stylesheet and add the styles to each element inline?

Comment: He is loading his HTML and CSS dynamically. So I'm just saying that to be sure that this external CSS would not break anything AND nobody would break his CSS, he should use CSS inline.

Comment: Inline styles only take precedence over whatever style you've cared to specify, what about the rest?  Are you going to specify them all?

Comment: Inline styles or stylesheet, they would only override those styles which were **common** between the main page's stylesheet and the dynamically loaded CSS.

Comment: I'm suggesting to not to load CSS dynamically, but use the style attribute on all elements that need to be styled on the banner. Is this so hard to understand?

Comment: It's a fair comment, a lot of HTML intended for web-based email would do it that way, but only as a compromise (an IFRAME or STYLE element would be rejected).